# How to destroy and recreate bean after each test class in spring boot

Tags: junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I have application where I create bean A which schedule tasks defined in configuration, but in tests I would like to create it bean before each test class and destroy after each class.

I need it because I update properties in each class, e.g.:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = ["my.property=valueForTest"])
```

Is it possible in JUnit/Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware only option to throw away whole context via `@DirtiesContext`. That obviously throws away also your bean.

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` should be fine in this case, since the original poster is creating an entirely new `ApplicationContext` per test class anyway (due to the use of `@TestPropertySource`).

Comment: Though I do have to point out that creating a new `ApplicationContext` for every test class is in fact, typically, a _worst practice_.